# Proving that if $f^{-1}((a, \infty]) \in\mathcal{S} \; \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am trying to prove:

> Suppose $(X, S)$ is a measurable space and $f:X\mapsto[-\infty, \infty]$ is a function such that
> \begin{align}
>      f^{-1}((a, \infty]) \in\mathcal{S}
>  \end{align}
> for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.

This is how I began this proof:
Let $\mathcal{T}=\{A\subset\mathbb{R}: f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{S}\}$. Then it suffices to show that every Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is in $\mathcal{T}$. To do this, I showed that $\mathcal{T}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ (for the sake of this question, let's assume that I did this correctly). By hypothesis, $\mathcal{T}$ contains $\{(a, \infty]: a \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

This is where I got stuck. I don't know how to complete the proof after this step. I was thinking of writing $(a, \infty] = \cap_{k=1}^\infty\left(a, \infty-\frac{1}{k}\right)$, but I am not sure how to use this to complete the proof. How can I complete the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish the proof, we must show that every basic open set is an element of $\mathcal{T}$. This follows from the fact that $\mathcal{T}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and contains all opens of the form $(a, \infty]$.

This is because we have all sets of the form $[-\infty, b]$ as elements of $\mathcal{T}$ by complementing the sets $[a, \infty)$. And $\bigcup\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}, q < a} [-\infty, q] = [-\infty, a)$.

To get the set $(a, b)$, just take $[-\infty, b) \cap (a, \infty]$.

Then we have the "basic open sets" of $[-\infty, \infty]$, which are intervals $[-\infty, a)$, $(a, b)$, and $(a, \infty]$. And any open set of $[-\infty, \infty]$ can be written as a countable union of these basic open sets. So we see that $\mathcal{T}$ contains all open sets. Hence, the Borel algebra is a subset of $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: By hypothesis, we only know that $\mathcal{T}$ contains $\{(a, \infty]: a \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Does this imply that $\mathcal{T}$ contains $\{(a, \infty): a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ as well? If yes, how?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson I have fixed my answer to account for this.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson Suppose $x < a$. Then there exists a rational number $q$ such that $x < q < a$, since the rationals are dense. Then $x \in [\infty, q]$. On the other hand, suppose $q < a$. Then clearly, $[-\infty, b] \subseteq [-\infty, a)$.

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks!